# Nurse Rostering Code with custom constraints Not Working

Tags: modeling, python, cp-sat

Could someone please check this code. I modified constraints as :

- No. of nurses - 10
- Max No. of nurses in Morning/Afternoon/Evening Shifts - 3/4/2
- Max no. of shifts in a week per nurse - 5

```
    from ortools.sat.python import cp_model    
    
    class NursesPartialSolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
        """Print intermediate solutions."""
    
        def __init__(self, shifts, num_nurses, num_days, num_shifts, sols):
            cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
            self._shifts = shifts
            self._num_nurses = num_nurses
            self._num_days = num_days
            self._num_shifts = num_shifts
            self._solutions = set(sols)
            self._solution_count = 0
    
        def on_solution_callback(self):
            if self._solution_count in self._solutions:
                print('Solution %i' % self._solution_count)
                for d in range(self._num_days):
                    print('Day %i' % d)
                    for n in range(self._num_nurses):
                        is_working = False
                        for s in range(self._num_shifts):
                            if self.Value(self._shifts[(n, d, s)]):
                                is_working = True
                                print('  Nurse %i works shift %i' % (n, s))
                        if not is_working:
                            print('  Nurse {} does not work'.format(n))
                print()
            self._solution_count += 1
    
        def solution_count(self):
            return self._solution_count
    
    
    
    def main():
        # Data.
        num_nurses = 10
        num_shifts = 3
        num_days = 7
        all_nurses = range(num_nurses)
        all_shifts = range(num_shifts)
        all_days = range(num_days)
        # Creates the model.
        model = cp_model.CpModel()
    
        # Creates shift variables.
        # shifts[(n, d, s)]: nurse 'n' works shift 's' on day 'd'.
        shifts = {}
        for n in all_nurses:
            for d in all_days:
                for s in all_shifts:
                    shifts[(n, d,
                            s)] = model.NewBoolVar('shift_n%id%is%i' % (n, d, s))
    
        # Each shift is assigned to exactly one nurse in the schedule period.
        for d in all_days:
            for s in all_shifts:
                if s==0:
                    model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) <= 3)
                if s==1:
                    model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) <= 4)
                if s==2:
                    model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) <= 2)
     
    
            
        # Each nurse works at most one shift per day.
        for n in all_nurses:
            for d in all_days:
                model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for s in all_shifts) <= 1)
    
        # Try to distribute the shifts evenly, so that each nurse works
        # min_shifts_per_nurse shifts. If this is not possible, because the total
        # number of shifts is not divisible by the number of nurses, some nurses will
        # be assigned one more shift.
        min_shifts_per_nurse = (num_shifts * num_days) // num_nurses
        if num_shifts * num_days % num_nurses == 0:
            max_shifts_per_nurse = min_shifts_per_nurse
        else:
            max_shifts_per_nurse = 5
        for n in all_nurses:
            num_shifts_worked = 0
            for d in all_days:
                for s in all_shifts:
                    num_shifts_worked += shifts[(n, d, s)]
            model.Add(min_shifts_per_nurse <= num_shifts_worked)
            model.Add(num_shifts_worked <= max_shifts_per_nurse)
    
        # Creates the solver and solve.
        solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
        solver.parameters.linearization_level = 0
        # Display the first five solutions.
        a_few_solutions = range(5)
        solution_printer = NursesPartialSolutionPrinter(shifts, num_nurses,
                                                        num_days, num_shifts,
                                                        a_few_solutions)
        solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, solution_printer)
    
        # Statistics.
        print()
        print('Statistics')
        print('  - conflicts       : %i' % solver.NumConflicts())
        print('  - branches        : %i' % solver.NumBranches())
        print('  - wall time       : %f s' % solver.WallTime())
        print('  - solutions found : %i' % solution_printer.solution_count())
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

It's not showing correct solutions as per constraints:

```
Solution 0
Day 0
  Nurse 0 works shift 1
  Nurse 1 works shift 0
  Nurse 2 works shift 0
  Nurse 3 does not work
  Nurse 4 works shift 0
  Nurse 5 works shift 1
  Nurse 6 works shift 1
  Nurse 7 works shift 1
  Nurse 8 works shift 2
  Nurse 9 works shift 2
Day 1
  Nurse 0 works shift 2
  Nurse 1 does not work
  Nurse 2 works shift 1
  Nurse 3 does not work
  Nurse 4 does not work
  Nurse 5 works shift 1
  Nurse 6 works shift 1
  Nurse 7 works shift 0
  Nurse 8 works shift 0
  Nurse 9 works shift 0
Day 2
  Nurse 0 does not work
  Nurse 1 does not work
  Nurse 2 does not work
  Nurse 3 does not work
  Nurse 4 does not work
  Nurse 5 does not work
  Nurse 6 does not work
  Nurse 7 does not work
  Nurse 8 does not work
  Nurse 9 does not work
Day 3
  Nurse 0 does not work
  Nurse 1 does not work
  Nurse 2 does not work
  Nurse 3 works shift 1
  Nurse 4 works shift 1
  Nurse 5 does not work
  Nurse 6 does not work
  Nurse 7 does not work
  Nurse 8 does not work
  Nurse 9 does not work
Day 4
  Nurse 0 does not work
  Nurse 1 does not work
  Nurse 2 does not work
  Nurse 3 does not work
  Nurse 4 does not work
  Nurse 5 does not work
  Nurse 6 does not work
  Nurse 7 does not work
  Nurse 8 does not work
  Nurse 9 does not work
Day 5
  Nurse 0 does not work
  Nurse 1 does not work
  Nurse 2 does not work
  Nurse 3 does not work
  Nurse 4 does not work
  Nurse 5 does not work
  Nurse 6 does not work
  Nurse 7 does not work
  Nurse 8 does not work
  Nurse 9 does not work
Day 6
  Nurse 0 does not work
  Nurse 1 works shift 2
  Nurse 2 does not work
  Nurse 3 works shift 2
  Nurse 4 does not work
  Nurse 5 does not work
  Nurse 6 does not work
  Nurse 7 does not work
  Nurse 8 does not work
  Nurse 9 does not work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't added lower bound for shift requirements so here's working code:

```
    from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

    class NursesPartialSolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    """Print intermediate solutions."""

    def __init__(self, shifts, num_nurses, num_days, num_shifts, sols):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self._shifts = shifts
        self._num_nurses = num_nurses
        self._num_days = num_days
        self._num_shifts = num_shifts
        self._solutions = set(sols)
        self._solution_count = 0

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        if self._solution_count in self._solutions:
            print('Solution %i' % self._solution_count)
            for d in range(self._num_days):
                print('Day %i' % d)
                for n in range(self._num_nurses):
                    is_working = False
                    for s in range(self._num_shifts):
                        if self.Value(self._shifts[(n, d, s)]):
                            is_working = True
                            print('  Nurse %i works shift %i' % (n, s))
                    if not is_working:
                        print('  Nurse {} does not work'.format(n))
            print()
        self._solution_count += 1

    def solution_count(self):
        return self._solution_count



def main():
    # Data.
    num_nurses = 10
    num_shifts = 3
    num_days = 7
    all_nurses = range(num_nurses)
    all_shifts = range(num_shifts)
    all_days = range(num_days)
    # Creates the model.
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    # Creates shift variables.
    # shifts[(n, d, s)]: nurse 'n' works shift 's' on day 'd'.
    shifts = {}
    for n in all_nurses:
        for d in all_days:
            for s in all_shifts:
                shifts[(n, d,
                        s)] = model.NewBoolVar('shift_n%id%is%i' % (n, d, s))

    # Each shift is assigned to exactly one nurse in the schedule period.
    for d in all_days:
        for s in all_shifts:
            if s==0:
                model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) <= 3)
                model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) >= 2)
            if s==1:
                model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) <= 4)
                model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) >= 2)
            if s==2:
                model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) <= 2)
                model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses) >= 1)



    # Each nurse works at most one shift per day.
    for n in all_nurses:
        for d in all_days:
            model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for s in all_shifts) <= 1)

    # Try to distribute the shifts evenly, so that each nurse works
    # min_shifts_per_nurse shifts. If this is not possible, because the total
    # number of shifts is not divisible by the number of nurses, some nurses will
    # be assigned one more shift.
    min_shifts_per_nurse = (num_shifts * num_days) // num_nurses
    if num_shifts * num_days % num_nurses == 0:
        max_shifts_per_nurse = min_shifts_per_nurse
    else:
        max_shifts_per_nurse = 5
    for n in all_nurses:
        num_shifts_worked = 0
        for d in all_days:
            for s in all_shifts:
                num_shifts_worked += shifts[(n, d, s)]
        model.Add(min_shifts_per_nurse <= num_shifts_worked)
        model.Add(num_shifts_worked <= max_shifts_per_nurse)

    # Creates the solver and solve.
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.parameters.linearization_level = 0
    # Display the first five solutions.
    a_few_solutions = range(20)
    solution_printer = NursesPartialSolutionPrinter(shifts, num_nurses,
                                                    num_days, num_shifts,
                                                    a_few_solutions)
    solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, solution_printer)

    # Statistics.
    print()
    print('Statistics')
    print('  - conflicts       : %i' % solver.NumConflicts())
    print('  - branches        : %i' % solver.NumBranches())
    print('  - wall time       : %f s' % solver.WallTime())
    print('  - solutions found : %i' % solution_printer.solution_count())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```